# PHP How to put all array values ​from a file into a CURL attachment

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api, foreach

I have a log.txt file that stores 5 IDs:

> 1776557086564
> 1776565635445
> 1776550836534
> 1776553308854
> 1776556565534

I want to take all the IDs in that file and then put the value into an attachment array in CURL with this format

```
'attached_media[0]' => '{"media_fbid":"1776557086564"}',
'attached_media[1]' => '{"media_fbid":"1776565635445"}',
'attached_media[2]' => '{"media_fbid":"1776550836534"}',
'attached_media[3]' => '{"media_fbid":"1776553308854"}',
'attached_media[4]' => '{"media_fbid":"1776556565534"}',
```

I use this code for CURL execution but it doesn't work.

```
    $file_lines = file('log.txt');

    foreach ($file_lines as $key=>$fbid) {
    $fbid = trim($fbid);    
    $attachMedia = 'attached_media[$key]';
    $media_fbid = '{"media_fbid":"[$fbid]"}';
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    $attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => $token,
                            'message'       => $caption,
                             $attachMedia   => $media_fbid                      
                        );
```

Error messege

> there is error{"error":{"message":"(#100) param attached_media must be an array.","type":"OAuthException"

Comment: The attached_media is a string. Your loop should be creating it as an array. 
Instead of $attachMedia = 'attached_media[$key]'; and $media_fbid = '{"media_fbid":"[$fbid]"}'; Try attached_media[$key] = '{"media_fbid":"[$fbid]"}'; Also remember to set attached_media as an empty array before the loop.

Comment: Also PHP doesn't expand variables in single quotes.